# I am having trouble understanding parts of this ruby bubble sort implementation?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand the following bubble sort implementation in ruby.  The main thing I don't understand is the use of the `sorted` variable.
I've commented the parts I find most confusing, and I'd greatly appreciate an explanation on the use of the `sorted` variable.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    sorted = false  #set sorted to false because array is not yet sorted..correct?
    until sorted  #this is where I get confused..this means until false..right? Shouldn't it be until true?
        sorted = true #this makes a little more sense.  Now sorted = true, so until = false isn't satisfied
        (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
            if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                sorted = false #so now sorted = false, shouldn't this mean the loop stops? How does the program go through more than one iteration of the until loop?
            end
        end
    end
    arr
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`until sorted` is like saying `while !sorted`

With that in mind, I think this should make better sense.

Ruby has a similar construct for `if` statements.  You can say
`unless foo` which means the same as `if !foo` .   Sometimes these types of expressions are confusing because they can be double negatives.

However if you just read the code out loud it should make sense...

until the array is sorted ... keep sorting it...

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but the `until` keyword's behavior is the opposite of your intuition.  The code

```
until X
    action
```

should be read "until `X` is true, repeat `action`," or, in other words "repeat `action` as long as `X` is false."

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    sorted = false  #sorted varriable is equal to false
    until sorted  #until sorted variable is true, this code will run
        sorted = true #sorted variable is now true
        (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
            if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                sorted = false #sorted variable is now set to false, so loop will run again.
            end
        end
    end
    arr
end
```